# Stubbing methods in Golang unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, go

I've been thinking about this whole night, but still cannot find an elegant way to do this thing. Let's say I have a struct

```
type file struct {
    x int
}

func (f *file) filename() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s/%d.log", exportPath, f.x)
}

func (f *file) write(data []byte) {
    ...
    aFile = os.File.Open(f.filename())
    ...
}
```

Now I want to test write method and stub filename method to return temp filename. How can I do this? To the moment I found two options:

1. declare filename = func(f* file) and override it in test
2. make filename a field of the struct

But they both seem wrong in this case. So the question is - can I stub in any way this method? And in general - how to stub internal methods for testing (for external obviously dependency injection could work)

Answer (score 2):

Making filename a field of the struct is an elegant way.
The `filename` should be defined when new the struct.

```
type fileStruct {
    filename string
}

func newFileStruct(x int) *fileStruct {
    filename := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%d.log", exportPath, x)
    return &fileStruct{filename: filename}
}

func (f *fileStruct) write (data []byte) {
    ...
    file = os.File.Open(f.filename)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up making my structs 100% injectable, the code looks clear and concise and  tests like a charm!